# Recursive Directory Structure Listing Taking To Long To Process

Tags: c#, asp.net, directoryinfo

I am using the code below start at a path (root) provided by a GET variable and recursively go into every sub folder and display it's contents as list items. The path I'm using has about 3800 files and 375 sub folders. I takes about 45 seconds to render the page, is there any way I can cut this time down as this is unacceptable for my users.

```
string output;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    getDirectoryTree(Request.QueryString["path"]);
    itemWrapper.InnerHtml = output;
}

private void getDirectoryTree(string dirPath) {
    try {
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo rootDirectory = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(dirPath);
        foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo subDirectory in rootDirectory.GetDirectories()) {
            output = output + "<ul><li><a>" + Regex.Replace(subDirectory.Name, "_", " ");
            if (subDirectory.GetFiles().Length != 0 || subDirectory.GetDirectories().Length != 0) {
                output = output + " +</a>";
            } else {
                output = output + "</a>";
            }
            getDirectoryTree(subDirectory.FullName);
            if (subDirectory.GetFiles().Length != 0) {
                output = output + "<ul>";
                foreach (System.IO.FileInfo file in subDirectory.GetFiles()) {
                    output = output + "<li><a href='" + file.FullName + "'>" + file.Name + "</a></li>";
                }
                output = output + "</ul>";
            }
            output = output + "</li></ul>";
        }
    } catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException) {
        //This throws when we don't have access.
    }
}
```

Comment: Do your users have to see all the expanded items at once? Why don't you get the folders on demand as the user clicks through the structure?

Comment: Most of your performance hit will be in the disk I/O probably.

Comment: @Alex How would I go about that, C# + ASP.NET is new to me, I'm a Java Certified Associate, still learning all of the aspects to C# + ASP.NET.

Comment: @Lloyd This application is running on a $30k server in a datacenter, I work for a large corporation. I don't think I have to worry about I/O because the server is assigned a lund on a SAN from EMC(2) running enterprise flash disks (Enterprise level SSDs).

Comment: @Alex would I use code that is non recursive and just look to see if there is a subDirectory and on click navigate to another Path like display C:\First and when they click First\Second navigate to index.aspx?path=C:\First\Second ?

Comment: There should be nothing wrong with recursion though, especially on his very expensive machine and it's only a few files. I wonder about creating new `DirectoryInfo()` objects all the time, you can just use `Directory.GetDirectories()` and `Directory.GetFiles()` which return string lists which could be faster.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543308/display-folder-and-file-only-doc-docx-in-tree-view-with-thier-icon/14237005#14237005

Comment: @user2087843 I don't know about your infrastructure, but you could use AJAX calls to just retrieve the next 1 or 2 levels, according to what the user clicks. Imagine a Windows Explorer control. It gets directorys on demand as well.

Comment: @user2087843 Also, if you just need directory/file names, consider using Win32 API (FindFirstFile, FindNextFile) since DirectoryInfo is pretty expensive. I managed to get alot faster results with huge directories.

Comment: I am going to go the AJAX call route to retrieve the information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- You should use System.Text.StringBuilder (Good performance) instead of string concatenate(Immutable) Bad performance.
- You should use normal string replace function is not using complex search. subDirectory.Name.replace("_", " ");

Answer (score 0):

Main reason for slowness in your code is most likely multiple calls to GetFiles and GetDirectories. You are calling them over and over again in `if` conditions as well as in your initial lookups. You only need the counts only once. Also, adding strings aren't helping the cause.

Following code was able to run through my simple usb-drive in 300ms and return with over 400 folders and 11000 files. On slow network drive, it was able to return in 9 seconds for 4000 files in 300 folders. It can probably be further optimized with [Parallel.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx) during recursion.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    itemWrapper.InnerHtml = GetDirectory(Request.QueryString["path"]);
}

static string GetDirectory(string path)
{
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    var subdir = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path);
    var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path);
    output.Append("<ul><li><a>");
    output.Append(path.Replace("_", " "));
    output.Append(subdir.Length > 0 || files.Length > 0 ? "+</a>" : "</a>");

    foreach(var sb in subdir)
    {
        output.Append(GetDirectory(sb));
    }

    if (files.Length > 0)
    {
        output.Append("<ul>");
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            output.AppendFormat("<li><a href =\"{0}\">{1}</a></li>", file, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file));
        }
        output.Append("</ul>");
    }
    output.Append("</ul>");
    return output.ToString();
}
```